# What exactly <React.StrictMode></React.StrictMode> component does?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx, react-component

I found this component inside a React practice, but i don't know what's the exact behavior.

e.g.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <div id="cool-attribute">
        <h1>Welcome to the Jungle!</h1>
        <SearchParams />
      </div>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};
```

Comment: I recommanded you to see the doc : https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to understand is What actually a *Strict Mode* is.

Strict Mode is a mode in which compiler gets extra careful with some additional instructions, does not eliminate silent errors on its own instead throws them out and put more limitations while coding. For more information, please [follow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

`React.StrictMode` is a same thing but to provide more limitations while working specifically with React. Here is a comprehensive [guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

If you are expecting something in UI, please stop because according to `React.StrictMode` documentation:

> StrictMode does not render any visible UI. It activates additional checks and warnings for its descendants.

Comment: Ohh I understand now, I'll check documentation, thank you.